# How to insert uploaded image into varbinary(max) database column

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

I want process form submit and save jpg image into varbinary sql column.
I have code but it does not work properly, it is saving only empty bytes like `0x00...0000`. So no errors are raised and database row is inserted successfully, but varbinary column seems to me corrupted.

The code is following

**Models**

```
public class FrontendModel
    {
        public HttpPostedFileBase Photo1 { get; set; }
    }

public class SubmitModel
    {
        public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
        public decimal ImageSizeB { get; set; }

        public SubmitModel
        (
            HttpPostedFileBase Photo
        )
        {

            this.ImageData = new byte[Photo.ContentLength];
            Photo.InputStream.Read(ImageData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(Photo.ContentLength));

        this.ImageSizeB = Photo.ContentLength;
    }
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(FrontendModel m)
{

    using (var db = new ABC.Models.ABCDBContext())
    {

        using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            if (m.Photo1 != null && m.Photo1.ContentLength > 0)
                db.InsertSubmit(new SubmitModel(m.Photo1));

            scope.Complete();
        }
    }

    return View(new FrontendModel());
}
```

**DB Insert Function**

```
public void InsertSubmit(SubmitModel m)
{
    Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
        "spInsertSubmit @p1",
        new SqlParameter("p1", m.ImageData),
    );
}
```

**SQL DB Procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertSubmit]
    @ImageData VARBINARY(max)
AS
        INSERT INTO dbo.Images (Image)
        VALUES (@ImageData)
```

what am I doing wrong ? Thank you

PS:

I also tried something like this but it behave the same

```
using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(Photo.InputStream))
            {
                this.ImageData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Photo.ContentLength);
            }
```

then I tried

```
using (Stream inputStream = Photo.InputStream)
            {
                MemoryStream memoryStream = inputStream as MemoryStream;
                if (memoryStream == null)
                {
                    memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                    inputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                }
                ImageData = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
```

but error shows in calling DB function with error message, `Parameter is not valid`

i have the same problem as is mentioned here
[File uploading and saving to database incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127322/file-uploading-and-saving-to-database-incorrectly)

[image]

I found that when i assign Input stream to memory stream, the memory stream is empty ?!

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure specifies that the parameter is called @ImageData but your code

```
  Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
        "spInsertSubmit @p1",
        new SqlParameter("p1", m.ImageData),
    );
```

seems to be passing a parameter called @p1

---

Edit

Also I think that you have to specify the type explicitly when working with a byte array larger than 8k. See this link: [Inserting a byte array larger than 8k bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111056/inserting-a-byte-array-larger-than-8k-bytes)

```
 Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
        "spInsertSubmit @p1",
        new SqlParameter("@p1", SqlDbType.VarBinary) { Value = m.ImageData },
    );
```

Comment: thank you, it was a typo in a question but in the code it is okay. Also I can upload 2MB data but the problem is that the binary is corrupted.

Comment: Are  you specifying the type explicitly as per the edit ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand you, in insertion I do not specify the varbinary type, I only past byte[] variable.

Comment: Thank you i tried it but now it was stored only "0x" record and not "0x0000..0" as before. I dont know what iam doing wrong :/

Comment: Another possible typo: Image instead of ImageData  in your stored procedure definition?

Comment: I edited it, there are no syntax errors in the code, the data are stored into database successfully, only varbinary column is corrupted :/ contains only "0x" or "0x000...0" values. Source images which are uploaded are okay.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a solution. This code works!

```
this.ImageData = new byte[streamLength];
Photo.InputStream.Position = 0;
Photo.InputStream.Read(this.ImageData, 0, this.ImageData.Length);
```

The line added is **Photo.InputStream.Position = 0;**